Using SQL LIKE operator in MongoDB indexes
I have a Flask app that queries my self-managed MongoDB.
I've created an index on two fields so that I can perform a text search on it.
The search is working fine, but it is only matching full words.
For example, for the phrase "i am halfminded", if I perform a search with the keyword halfminded it works but doesn't work for half.
This is what i am using:
    def get_paginated_data(self, page, query):
    skip = (page - 1) * self.PER_PAGE
    data = (
        self.collection.find({"$text": {"$search": query}})
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(self.PER_PAGE)
    )
    return list(data)

I have tried using the below code as well:
def get_paginated_data(self, page, query):
    skip = (page - 1) * self.PER_PAGE
    data = (
        self.collection.find({"$text": {"$regex": f"/.*{query}/"}})
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(self.PER_PAGE)
    )
    return list(data)

but this throws the following error:
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Missing expected field "$search"

Can anyone advise on how i can get the partial text search to work.

Does this answer your question? How to find a substring in a field in Mongodb

Nope. The answer says to use $regex. That's what i did in my example above and i landed on an error because i am using indexes. Apparently if i use indexes i have to use the search keyword.

Why you must use $text and text index? You can simply use a normal index and do the regex search like this, if a substring search is what you are looking for
